Why does Eric claim his visit to the Sierra Madre Occidental is personal?
The protagonist of Anita Desai's The Zigzag Way, Eric, is an academic struggling with his research project. He has been given a grant to write a book on immigration, but feels uninspired. His girlfriend, Em, is traveling to Mexico as a research scientist. Telling himself (and her) that he might find fresh ideas for his work there, Eric decides to accompany Em. In the process, he more or less accidentally discovers that his Cornish grandfather David Rowse had spent some time as a migrant miner in Mexico, and that his grandmother Betty Jennings died there giving birth to his father. Intrigued, Eric decides to travel to the ghost towns of Sierra Madre Occidental to learn what he can about the miners and hopefully locate Betty's grave.
Near his destination, he spends a night at la Hacienda de la Soledad, an anthropological research center for Huichol studies. He knows that the founder, Doña Vera, holds the mining industry responsible for destroying the traditional lifestyle of the Huichol. Yet when asked about the reason for his visit, Eric makes two surprising blunders during successive encounters with the lady. First, he says that his visit is personal, earning Doña Vera's scorn:

"You have an interest in an-thro-pol-ogy? In the Huichol Indian?"
Eric could only lie to be polite and avoid inflicting pain, not for any boastful reason. "Not really," he muttered, hoping the yipping of the pugs would drown out his craven response. He found himself actually shuffling his shoes. Now, if he had been the delivery man of a patisserie, he thought ruefully. Instead, he had to admit, "It's for a personal reason ..."
But she had already decided he was of no interest and no importance. Rising from her chair with one pug in her arms, the others milling at her feet, she started toward the house, calling over her shoulder, "Here we conduct se-rious studies, señor."
Desai, Anita. The Zigzag Way. Boston: Houghton Mifflin, 2004. p. 39.

Next, he reveals that he is interested in the mines, and reminds Doña Vera that the fortune with which she has set up the Huichol research center came from her marriage to a mining baron. This gets her dander up even more:

"I founded my center to pro-tect them, their en-vi-ron-ment, their his-tory, and re-li-gion. I am not one of those who took their land and ru-ined it with mining and made them slaves. Whoever tells you this, lies. ... If it is mines you are interested in, then it is not to me you should come. Not to my center. Here we work to keep the cul-ture and re-li-gion and art of the Huichol a-live that the min-ing in-dus-try near-ly de-stroy-ed. On the one hand is greed, señor, on the other — respect!"
ibid., p. 49

I do not understand why Eric blunders in this fashion. He has a paid fellowship to research immigration. He has come to Mexico hoping to get some inspiration for his work. He finds that inspiration in the story of Cornish immigrant miners. Granting that his family history draws him to this subject, it would nevertheless be both tactful and true enough to claim that he wanted to research the connections between the mining companies that enslaved the Huichol, then replaced them with migrant workers. Why does Eric antagonize Doña Vera by claiming a personal interest in the mines, instead of framing it as part of his professional research project?
